# Display image converted to numpy array in Tkinter with PIL

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to load image with PIL, then convert it to array (for further manipulations) and then convert it back to image and show it in Tkinter Label element. I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL as pl
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np

root = Tk()
root_panel = Frame(root)
root_panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

img_src = 'pic.jpg'
img = pl.Image.open(img_src)
img_arr = np.array(img)
img = pl.Image.fromarray(img_arr)

img_panel = Label(root_panel)
img_panel.configure(image=img)
img_panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

root.mainloop()
```

When I run it got a mistake:

```
File "C:/Users/lazar/Documents/GitHub/Face-Features-Detection/ui.py", line 19, in <module>
    img_panel.configure(image=img)
  File "C:\Users\a\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1479, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\a\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1470, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=295x400 at 0x28CAB9F5630>" doesn't exist
```

It seems to find it (`<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=295x400 at 0x28CAB9F5630>`), but for some reason print that it doesn't exist. Can anyone please suggest what may cause this problem?

Comment: `tkinter` can't display `Image` - it can display only `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this:

```
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
img_panel = Label(root_panel)
img_panel.configure(image=img_tk)
```

Comment: PIL appears to now be maintained as pillow. I had to pip install pillow  (rather than PIL)

Answer (score 0):

While this question seems resolved, I would like to add a link to "ripple tank simulator" that updates the TkInter canvas in real time, supporting colormaps, embossing, (un)zooming etc.

https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/14761052f42d80d283bd3adcf7eb5347

It depends on TkInter + numpy only. I tried to optimize it for speed without making it overly complicated.